# getting the same height for two side by side pgfplot figures

Tags: pgfplots, scaling

I display two side by side pgfplots which dont have the same xmax and ymax.
In a first case with (xmin=-1,xmax=3,ymin=-1,ymax=11) the two plots have the same height (see EXAMPLE 1).
In a second case with (xmin=-1,xmax=12,ymin=-1,ymax=7) the two plots do not have exactly the same height. But I would like them to have the same height (see EXAMPLE 2).
Maybe one has to do something specific when ymax-ymin is less than xmax-xmin ?

EXAMPLE 1 (with the same height)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

\def\argument#1{\mathtt{#1}}
\def\constraint#1{\textsc{#1}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm]
\begin{axis}[axis equal image=true,xlabel={nb\_bump\_on\_decreasing\_sequence},
ylabel={nb\_decreasing},
title style={yshift=1.2ex},
title={$\argument{sv}=12$},
xtick ={0,2,...,2},
ytick ={0,2,...,10},
minor tick num=1,
grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!20},
xmin=-1,xmax=4,
ymin=-1,ymax=12,
extra description/.code={
 \node (description1) at (c1) {\large\ding{172}};
 \node (description2) at (c2) {\large\ding{173}};
 \node (description3) at (c3) {\large\ding{174}};
 \node (description4) at (c4) {\large\ding{175}};
}
]
\addplot[blue!20,only marks] coordinates {(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(0,5)(0,6)(0,7)(0,8)(0,9)(0,10)(0,11)};
\addplot[blue!50,only marks] coordinates {(1,4)(1,5)(1,6)(1,7)(1,8)(1,9)(1,10)(2,6)(2,7)(2,8)(2,9)(3,8)};
\addplot[red,only marks] coordinates {(1,3)};
\addplot[blue!50,densely dashed] coordinates {(0,0)(3,8)(0,11)(0,0)(0,0)};
\draw[fill=pink,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1.5,-1) -- (axis cs:5.0,12) -- (axis cs:5.0,12) -- 
                             (axis cs:5.0,-1) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick] coordinates {(-1.5,-1)(5.0,12)};
\draw[fill=pink,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1,4) -- (axis cs:4,4) -- (axis cs:4,-1) --
                             (axis cs:-1,-1) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick] coordinates {(-1,4)(4,4)};
\draw[fill=cyan,opacity=0.2] (axis cs:-1,12.0) -- (axis cs:4,7.0) -- (axis cs:4,12) -- (axis cs:-1,12) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!50,thick] coordinates {(-1,12.0)(4,7.0)};
\addplot[orange] coordinates {(1,3)(4,3)};
\addplot[orange,only marks,mark=otimes*]coordinates {(1,3)};
\addplot[orange,only marks,mark=diamond*]coordinates {(2,3)(3,3)};
\coordinate (c1) at (axis cs:4.6,10.0);
\coordinate (c2) at (axis cs:4.6,4);
\coordinate (c3) at (axis cs:4.6,7.0);
\coordinate (c4) at (axis cs:4.6,3);
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=10cm,yshift=0cm]
\begin{axis}[axis equal image=true,xlabel={nb\_bump\_on\_decreasing\_sequence},
ylabel={nb\_decreasing},
title style={yshift=1.2ex},
title={$\argument{sv}=11$},
xtick ={0,2,...,3},
ytick ={0,2,...,11},
minor tick num=1,
grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!20},
xmin=-1,xmax=3,
ymin=-1,ymax=11,
extra description/.code={
 \node (description1) at (c1) {\large\ding{172}};
 \node (description2) at (c2) {\large\ding{173}};
 \node (description3) at (c3) {\large\ding{174}};
 \node (description4) at (c4) {\large\ding{175}};
}
]
\addplot[blue!20,only marks] coordinates {(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(0,5)(0,6)(0,7)(0,8)(0,9)(0,10)};
\addplot[blue!50,only marks] coordinates {(1,4)(1,5)(1,6)(1,7)(1,8)(1,9)(2,6)(2,7)(2,8)};
\addplot[red,only marks] coordinates {(1,3)};
\addplot[blue!50,densely dashed] coordinates {(0,0)(2,6)(2,8)(0,10)(0,0)(0,0)};
\draw[fill=pink,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1.5,-1) -- (axis cs:4.5,11) -- (axis cs:4.5,11) --
                             (axis cs:4.5,-1) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick] coordinates {(-1.5,-1)(4.5,11)};
\draw[fill=pink,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1,4) -- (axis cs:3,4) -- (axis cs:3,-1) --
                             (axis cs:-1,-1) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick] coordinates {(-1,4)(3,4)};
\draw[fill=cyan,opacity=0.2] (axis cs:-1,11.0) -- (axis cs:3,7.0) -- (axis cs:3,11) --
                             (axis cs:-1,11) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!50,thick] coordinates {(-1,11.0)(3,7.0)};
\addplot[orange] coordinates {(1,3)(3,3)};
\addplot[orange,only marks,mark=otimes*]coordinates {(1,3)};
\addplot[orange,only marks,mark=diamond*]coordinates {(2,3)};
\coordinate (c1) at (axis cs:3.55,8.0);
\coordinate (c2) at (axis cs:3.55,4);
\coordinate (c3) at (axis cs:3.55,7.0);
\coordinate (c4) at (axis cs:3.55,3);
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EXAMPLE 2 (where the heights differ)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

\def\argument#1{\mathtt{#1}}
\def\constraint#1{\textsc{#1}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm]
\begin{axis}[axis equal image=true,xlabel={nb\_decreasing},
ylabel={nb\_steady\_sequence},
title style={yshift=1.2ex},
title={$\argument{sv}=12$},
xtick ={0,2,...,10},
ytick ={0,2,...,7},
minor tick num=1,
grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!20},
xmin=-1,xmax=12,
ymin=-1,ymax=7,
extra description/.code={
 \node (description1) at (c1) {\large\ding{172}};
}
]
\addplot[blue!20,only marks]
    coordinates {(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(0,5)(0,6)(1,0)(2,0)(3,0)(4,0)(5,0)(6,0)(7,0)(8,0)(9,0)(10,0)(11,0)};
\addplot[blue!50,only marks]
    coordinates {(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(1,4)(1,5)(1,6)(2,1)(2,2)(2,3)(2,4)(2,5)(2,6)(3,1)(3,2)(3,3)(3,4)(3,5)(3,6)(4,1)(4,2)(4,3)(4,4)(4,5)(4,6)(5,1)(5,2)(5,3)(5,4)(5,5)(5,6)(6,1)(6,2)(6,3)(6,4)(6,5)(7,1)(7,2)(7,3)(7,4)(8,1)(8,2)(8,3)(9,1)(9,2)(10,1)};
\addplot[blue!50,densely dashed]
    coordinates {(0,0)(11,0)(5,6)(0,6)(0,0)(0,0)};
\draw[fill=cyan,opacity=0.2] (axis cs:-1,12.0) -- (axis cs:12,-1.0) -- (axis cs:12,12) --
                             (axis cs:-1,12) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!50,thick] coordinates {(-1,12.0)(12,-1.0)};
\coordinate (c1) at (axis cs:12.6,-1.0);
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=10cm,yshift=0cm]
\begin{axis}[axis equal image=true,xlabel={nb\_decreasing},
ylabel={nb\_steady\_sequence},
title style={yshift=1.2ex},
title={$\argument{sv}=11$},
xtick ={0,2,...,11},
ytick ={0,2,...,4},
minor tick num=1,
grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!20},
xmin=-1,xmax=11,
ymin=-1,ymax=6,
extra description/.code={
 \node (description1) at (c1) {\large\ding{172}};
}
]
\addplot[blue!20,only marks] coordinates {(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(0,5)(1,0)(2,0)(3,0)(4,0)(5,0)(6,0)(7,0)(8,0)(9,0)(10,0)};
\addplot[blue!50,only marks] coordinates {(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(1,4)(1,5)(2,1)(2,2)(2,3)(2,4)(2,5)(3,1)(3,2)(3,3)(3,4)(3,5)(4,1)(4,2)(4,3)(4,4)(4,5)(5,1)(5,2)(5,3)(5,4)(5,5)(6,1)(6,2)(6,3)(6,4)(7,1)(7,2)(7,3)(8,1)(8,2)(9,1)};
\addplot[blue!50,densely dashed] coordinates {(0,0)(10,0)(5,5)(0,5)(0,0)(0,0)};
\draw[fill=cyan,opacity=0.2] (axis cs:-1,11.0) -- (axis cs:11,-1.0) -- (axis cs:11,11) --
                             (axis cs:-1,11) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!50,thick] coordinates {(-1,11.0)(11,-1.0)};
\coordinate (c1) at (axis cs:11.55,-1.0);
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's related to `axis equal image=true`, with that set to `false` they're the same height.

Comment: When I use axis equal image=false, it makes things worse, the two heights are more "unbalanced"

Comment: Not if you set that for *both* `axis` environments, then they're the same.

Comment: Shouldn't sv11 be shorter in *both* directions? For the sake of comparability, it would be better to have equal lengths of units in both plots, with differing plot height and width. Or you can expand sv11 plot to include one more unit to both y and x axes. This way, your plots will have the same dimension AND the same unit lengths. Much better comparability imho.

Comment: Unrelated: What do the diagrams represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think perhaps what you're seeing is related to the documented behaviour for `axis equal image`. With that setting, `pgfplots` will happily rescale an `axis` so it no longer conforms to the `height`/`width` setting. The `axis equal` setting on the other hand, will respect the `height`/`width` setting, by adjusting the axis limits.

Depending on your requirements, either not using `axis equal image`, or using `axis equal` instead, might be a solution, and in addition set both `width` and `height` explicitly. (I used `width=6cm, height=4.5cm` below.)

Not related to your question, but you might be interested in the `groupplots` library, demonstrated below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand\argument[1]{\mathtt{#1}}
\newcommand\constraint[1]{\textsc{#1}}


\begin{document}

Without \texttt{axis equal image}:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group size=2 by 1,
    horizontal sep=1.5cm,
  },
  % set common options here
  footnotesize, % reduces font size of diagram
  xmin=-1,
  ymin=-1,
  width=6cm,
  height=4.5cm,
  ylabel={nb\_steady\_sequence},
  xlabel={nb\_decreasing},
  title style={yshift=1.2ex},
  minor tick num=1,
  xtick ={0,2,...,10},
  grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
  major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!20},
  extra description/.code={
   \node (description1) at (c1) {\large\ding{172}};
  }
]

\nextgroupplot[
  title={$\argument{sv}=12$},
  ytick ={0,2,...,7},
  xmax=12,
  ymax=7,
]
\addplot[blue!20,only marks]
    coordinates {(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(0,5)(0,6)(1,0)(2,0)(3,0)(4,0)(5,0)(6,0)(7,0)(8,0)(9,0)(10,0)(11,0)};
\addplot[blue!50,only marks]
    coordinates {(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(1,4)(1,5)(1,6)(2,1)(2,2)(2,3)(2,4)(2,5)(2,6)(3,1)(3,2)(3,3)(3,4)(3,5)(3,6)(4,1)(4,2)(4,3)(4,4)(4,5)(4,6)(5,1)(5,2)(5,3)(5,4)(5,5)(5,6)(6,1)(6,2)(6,3)(6,4)(6,5)(7,1)(7,2)(7,3)(7,4)(8,1)(8,2)(8,3)(9,1)(9,2)(10,1)};
\addplot[blue!50,densely dashed]
    coordinates {(0,0)(11,0)(5,6)(0,6)(0,0)(0,0)};
\draw[fill=cyan,opacity=0.2] (axis cs:-1,12.0) -- (axis cs:12,-1.0) -- (axis cs:12,12) --
                             (axis cs:-1,12) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!50,thick] coordinates {(-1,12.0)(12,-1.0)};
\coordinate (c1) at (axis cs:12.6,-1.0);

\nextgroupplot[
  title={$\argument{sv}=11$},
  ytick ={0,2,...,4},
  xmax=11,
  ymax=6,
]
\addplot[blue!20,only marks] coordinates {(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(0,5)(1,0)(2,0)(3,0)(4,0)(5,0)(6,0)(7,0)(8,0)(9,0)(10,0)};
\addplot[blue!50,only marks] coordinates {(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(1,4)(1,5)(2,1)(2,2)(2,3)(2,4)(2,5)(3,1)(3,2)(3,3)(3,4)(3,5)(4,1)(4,2)(4,3)(4,4)(4,5)(5,1)(5,2)(5,3)(5,4)(5,5)(6,1)(6,2)(6,3)(6,4)(7,1)(7,2)(7,3)(8,1)(8,2)(9,1)};
\addplot[blue!50,densely dashed] coordinates {(0,0)(10,0)(5,5)(0,5)(0,0)(0,0)};
\draw[fill=cyan,opacity=0.2] (axis cs:-1,11.0) -- (axis cs:11,-1.0) -- (axis cs:11,11) --
                             (axis cs:-1,11) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!50,thick] coordinates {(-1,11.0)(11,-1.0)};
\coordinate (c1) at (axis cs:11.55,-1.0);
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}


With \texttt{axis equal} instead of \texttt{axis equal image}:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group size=2 by 1,
    horizontal sep=1.5cm,
  },
  % set common options here
  axis equal,
  footnotesize, % reduces font size of diagram
  xmin=-1,
  ymin=-1,
  width=6cm,
  height=4.5cm,
  ylabel={nb\_steady\_sequence},
  xlabel={nb\_decreasing},
  title style={yshift=1.2ex},
  minor tick num=1,
  xtick ={0,2,...,10},
  grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
  major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!20},
  extra description/.code={
   \node (description1) at (c1) {\large\ding{172}};
  }
]

\nextgroupplot[
  title={$\argument{sv}=12$},
  ytick ={0,2,...,7},
  xmax=12,
  ymax=7,
]
\addplot[blue!20,only marks]
    coordinates {(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(0,5)(0,6)(1,0)(2,0)(3,0)(4,0)(5,0)(6,0)(7,0)(8,0)(9,0)(10,0)(11,0)};
\addplot[blue!50,only marks]
    coordinates {(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(1,4)(1,5)(1,6)(2,1)(2,2)(2,3)(2,4)(2,5)(2,6)(3,1)(3,2)(3,3)(3,4)(3,5)(3,6)(4,1)(4,2)(4,3)(4,4)(4,5)(4,6)(5,1)(5,2)(5,3)(5,4)(5,5)(5,6)(6,1)(6,2)(6,3)(6,4)(6,5)(7,1)(7,2)(7,3)(7,4)(8,1)(8,2)(8,3)(9,1)(9,2)(10,1)};
\addplot[blue!50,densely dashed]
    coordinates {(0,0)(11,0)(5,6)(0,6)(0,0)(0,0)};
\draw[fill=cyan,opacity=0.2] (axis cs:-1,12.0) -- (axis cs:12,-1.0) -- (axis cs:12,12) --
                             (axis cs:-1,12) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!50,thick] coordinates {(-1,12.0)(12,-1.0)};
\coordinate (c1) at (axis cs:12.6,-1.0);

\nextgroupplot[
  title={$\argument{sv}=11$},
  ytick ={0,2,...,4},
  xmax=11,
  ymax=6,
]
\addplot[blue!20,only marks] coordinates {(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(0,5)(1,0)(2,0)(3,0)(4,0)(5,0)(6,0)(7,0)(8,0)(9,0)(10,0)};
\addplot[blue!50,only marks] coordinates {(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(1,4)(1,5)(2,1)(2,2)(2,3)(2,4)(2,5)(3,1)(3,2)(3,3)(3,4)(3,5)(4,1)(4,2)(4,3)(4,4)(4,5)(5,1)(5,2)(5,3)(5,4)(5,5)(6,1)(6,2)(6,3)(6,4)(7,1)(7,2)(7,3)(8,1)(8,2)(9,1)};
\addplot[blue!50,densely dashed] coordinates {(0,0)(10,0)(5,5)(0,5)(0,0)(0,0)};
\draw[fill=cyan,opacity=0.2] (axis cs:-1,11.0) -- (axis cs:11,-1.0) -- (axis cs:11,11) --
                             (axis cs:-1,11) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!50,thick] coordinates {(-1,11.0)(11,-1.0)};
\coordinate (c1) at (axis cs:11.55,-1.0);
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How did you compute the values of width and height? If I set up width=6.5cm and heigth=4cm, I get some extra space on the right and the (1) inside the picture.

Comment: @NicolasBeldiceanu I didn't compute anything, that was just trial and error. I also don't see the other problems you mention. What do you get from the code in my answer?

Comment: @NicolasBeldiceanu By the way, if that circled `1` is supposed to be next to the bottom right corner of the axis, you can use `\node [right,inner sep=1pt] (description1) at (current axis.south east) {\large\ding{172}};`, which means you don't need to define the `c1` coordinate.

Comment: Since a few hundred pgfplots are produced by a program, I cannot use trial and error to find the proper value of width and height for each plot, I need some formula to compute from the two xmin and xmax

Comment: @NicolasBeldiceanu I see.  Just thinking out loud here: add `scale only axis` to the `axis` options, and choose some suitable maximum size (e.g. maxsize=5cm). If yrange > xrange, set the `height` to maxsize, and the `width` to maxsize * xrange/yrange. Similarly, if yrange < xrange, set the `width` to maxsize, and the `height` to maxsize * yrange/xrange. Of course if yrange=xrange, set both `width` and `height` to maxsize.

Comment: It works perfectly.